# How to generate a RandomWalk with n dimensions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, dimension, random-walk

How do i generate a RandomWalk with n dimensions?

I already have some examples for a 1 or 2 dimensional random walk but now i have to code a random walk with n dimensions and i seriously don't know how.

here are 2 examples for 2 dimensions:

```
 RandomWalk2DLattice[n_] := 
 Accumulate[Through[{Cos, Sin}[# \[Pi]/2]] & /@ RandomInteger[3, {n}]]
 rw = RandomWalk2DLattice[500];

 Show[Graphics[{Line[rw], {PointSize[.02], Point[rw[[{-1}]]], 
        Point[{0, 0}]}}, Axes -> True], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: Hint: Look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html and think of the various ways you can give it parameters. That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
ndim = 3;
walk = NestList[(d = RandomInteger[{1, ndim}]; 
         ReplacePart[#, d -> #[[d]] + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]]) &,
                ConstantArray[0, ndim], 1000];
```

[image]